# Can't save customers after migration Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, admin, customer, migration

After I migrated from Magento 1.9.3.8 to 2.2.5 although I can create new customers I can't edit and save the migrated ones. In admin, I get errors that First Name, Last Name, and other attributes are needed. But in customers, these fields are filled.
In

> system.log

I get:

```
[2019-02-16 12:55:39] report.WARNING: Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '1163'
                        for entity type 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'. [] []
[2019-02-16 12:55:39] report.WARNING: Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '1206'
                        for entity type 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'. [] []
```

and

```
[2019-02-16 12:57:27] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively [] []
```

I managed to remove the mentioned attributes which were product attributes. As continue investigation my problem is a Magento 2.2.5 bug or because Magento 1.9.3.8 was using Amasty customer attributes extension, these customer attributes were migrated to Magento 2 and created this problem.

When I save a migrated customer in admin I get:

> "First Name" is a required value.
>
> "First Name" length must be equal to or greater than 1 character.
>
> "Last Name" is a required value.
>
> "Last Name" length must be equal to or greater than 1 character.
>
> "Street Address" is a required value.
>
> "Street Address" length must be equal to or greater than 1 character.

But all these fields are correctly filled.

Can anyone help me what to check, please?
I am going crazy here...

Comment: It looks like few of product attributes are not migrated properly. You should check product attribute listing.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar probably you mean customer attributes. In Magento one I was using Amasty customer attributes....So I think these are the problem. How can I remove them from database?

Comment: You have to identify those attribute and removed them using UpgradeData.php

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar I found the attribute in eav attribute table. How can I remove them from database directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what happened and fixed. Some of the migrated customers had more than one address. In there the

> First Name
>
> Last Name
>
> Street Address

was empty.

When I edited the customers and delete that address without fill up these fields I got the error I posted.

I don't if it should work that way but now I fixed it and all customers saved fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happening because of validation file in `vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader` and in this function

```
 private function _setUploadFileId($fileId)
    {
        if (is_array($fileId)) {
            $this->validateFileId($fileId);
            $this->_uploadType = self::MULTIPLE_STYLE;
            $this->_file = $fileId;
        }
```

comment this following line in the above function:

```
// $this->validateFileId($fileId);
```

We can need to override the above function using
the following steps:
We can override using preference.

1. Create di.xml

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader" type="NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader" />
   ```
2. Create class php file
   In the given path put your fle `NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader`